# Can you sort columns (horizontally) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I understand how to sort rows in Google sheets, but there doesn't seem to seem to be a built-in way to sort columns like their is with Excel. Can this still be done in Google sheets?

For example,

```
   A B C
1  4 3 7
```

If I sorted largest to smallest it would go: Column C, Column A, Column B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done so:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A:C),2,))
```

(assuming `A`, `B` and `C` are labels in ColumnsA:C, change `2` to `1` if not).